Keep only essential packages centos,Almalinux
In an attempt to learn more about Centos,Almalinux and its packages, I want to remove all non-essential packages, so I can install what I need, when I need them and know what they do.
When using commands like yum list installed or rpm -qa, I get a comprehensive list of all installed packages. However, it's challenging to distinguish whether a package is crucial for the OS or not. I need a method to filter packages by their importance, so I can safely remove ones like MariaDB, Salt, Nginx, and similar packages that are not critical to the system's core functions.

What is or isn't essential is a matter of opinion. Damn Small Linux 2024 still fits in a CD.

This will almost certainly not be possible since we have no way of knowing what you consider essential and what you don't. Sure, the OS might "work" but not the various things you have installed. Instead of starting from a relatively complex, "bloated" system and trying to remove things, you might instead want to start with an extremely limited, streamlined system like Arch or Gentoo and then only add what you want.

You might also want to try installing a "minimal" system. This name may change depending on the distribution but the graphical OEL installer has a radiobox selection for "Minimal Install". From experience, this still has packages that are not strictly necessary for the system to be able to manage certain tasks. If you want to use the system as a firewall, you could essentially strip it down to support only iptables, bash, and sshd. It all depends on what you deem "essential". And, as @terdon suggested, I have used Gentoo in the past to build very streamlined systems.

@terdon
I also don't know which packages are important or not. For example, I have a new server and I want to filter packages by their importance, but I'm not sure if there is a method to do this. I'm looking for a command, Python script, or shell script to help with this task.
My goal is to format my server and remove only the non-essential packages without affecting the important packages or those related to the operating system.

That's the thing: what is important will depend on what your machine is doing. Just do it the other way around: start with a minimal system and build your way up, don't try to start with a complex system and make it simpler.

@terdon
You are right, but I don't have a choice. I am in a situation where I need to filter the packages. I can't choose which packages to install initially because there are already packages installed. I haven't found any method to filter the packages used by the OS and the important ones from the others.
I need a way to filter out the essential packages used by the operating system and distinguish them from the non-essential ones so I can remove them safely.

Yeah, but that's just it: there is no way to do this. Not without first deciding what is and what is not essential. Is networking essential? How about mounting remote drives? Is a DB essential? What does the server do?

@terdon
So, there isn't a method available to filter packages. I want to reset the server to a new state, keeping only the important packages for the OS and removing all other packages. As you mentioned, there isn't a method that allows filtering packages in this way.

As long as “core functions” is only being able to boot and run yum, yum and dnf will stop you from removing essential (“protected”) packages, so you can remove all non-essential packages by running
for package in $(rpm -qa); do yum remove "$package"; done

and manually confirming the valid removals.
This won’t break your system (at least, it will allow you to boot it and run yum), but it will make it significantly less useful.

Are tools for booting on, say, encrypted disks (e.g., whatever prompts for the password during boot) also in essential packages? If not, this might break booting.

Ah yes, that’s a good point, cryptsetup isn’t protected (even transitively), but cryptsetup-libs is — I’m not sure what’s required to set up decryption during boot.
